# Hibernate criteria. Left join question

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

The below SQL able to execute without error.  My first table has this field `this_.CHECKER_DATE`. When I do join with second table, there is query `customermo1_.CHECKER_DATE` which does not even exist in `customermo1_`.  Is this normal behavior of Hibernate?

Please see `show_sql` output at http://pastebin.com/sNpSvmSm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate knows what exists in your entities only from the mapping.

From what you wrote, it looks as if the mapping for customermo1_ has a field called CHECKER_DATE.